# how to change table some tr background color change using classes

Tags: html, css, html-table

how to add background color to a table row using class ,here i try my css and html are

```css
.main-table tbody td .main-table-row{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="main-table-row">
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="main-table-row">
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

above code is my try how to color tr using class any way?

Comment: `.main-table tbody td .main-table-row` <-- why is there a TD in there? selector says there is a TD between the Tbody and the class main-table-row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `td` in `.main-table tbody td .main-table-row`.

```css
.main-table tbody .main-table-row{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<table class="main-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                <th scope="col">Heading</th>
                <th scope="col">Heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="main-table-row">
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="main-table-row">
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">Type something</th>
                <td>Type something</td>
                <td>Type something</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```